# How to configure Jenkins to run tag / branch dynamically?

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to configure a Jenkins job to run the latest release build automatically (for the periodic builds option). Currently, the way that it is set up is that every new release version gets its own branch, each labeled something along the format of "Release x.x.x". If possible, I'd like to be able to dynamically run the latest branch without having to manually configure all of the jobs every time there is a new release.

Alternatively, it seems that using tags might be an alternative way to do this and I'm open to doing it that way as well.

I've been doing a good amount of research on this and from what I can find, using a git parameter is my best bet. Unfortunately, there's not a lot of documentation on how to use this. I've been trying with the tags as that seems like it would be easier since all of the tags are exclusively just version numbers so using the DESCENDING_SMART sort option would work better with that whereas with branches you also have the names of other miscellaneous branches to consider. I've set the tag filter to * and for the branch specifier it's set to "refs/tags/${RELEASE_TAG}" but this isn't working for me. When I go to build the parameter just says "Retrieving Git references...". And even if I can get that working I also need a way to set the default value to the latest build (I'm kind of banking on it to default to the first branch from the sorted list if no default is provided, or some alternative to get that to work).

Another idea I've had is to use a script to return the parameter value but I'm not sure if that's possible. I've seen some stuff about running a groovy script in the configuration but I haven't done much research into how that works, and even if I can run the script I need a way to securely access the repository and just get all the branch names. Once I have that it should be pretty trivial to return the latest release branch.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or am I going to just have to manually update the release version for every new release?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is the full situation I'm in:

I was asked to automate some of the existing Jenkins jobs we currently have to run overnight everyday. However, some of the jobs are failing because they require a release version parameter passed in, which currently is a string parameter with no default value set. The problem with adding a default value is that would mean every time we have a new release, we would need to go in to manually update the release version. Instead I'd like a system I can use to have Jenkins automatically determine the latest release (based on existing branches)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multi branch project , it will generate a build for every new branch.

You can use some regex **Release.**

Comment: I'm not fully sure what that is, and googling it says that it has been deprecated. But I don't think we want a build for every branch. We also have branches for every feature that we want to add as well and we don't want to be running or even have a jenkins job for every single branch


Edit: Just saw your update about the regex. I'm not familiar with how regex works, would it be possible for me to configure it so that it only chooses the most recent release (i.e. the first one to pop up using descending smart sort)?

Comment: You can build only specific branches - like all the branch start with Release. BTW which Jenkins version you are using ?

Comment: It's v1.628. 

And that sounds nearly perfect, is there a way to specify just the most recent release branch? We have a decent amount of release branches and the builds use a good amount of resources so running all of the release branches isn't viable in our case.

Comment: Maybe use some convention Release-1. And build all minors branches as well .another option start the flow and parse the git log if you have more than xx commits in 1 day / week continued the build

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You can pass the branch as parameter.

Create a string parameter in your job let's call "branch"

In 'Branches to build /Branch Specifier' use the parameter ${branch}

Now remotely trigger this build passing this parameter.

You can use git script hooks to accomplish that, a better way to do that is run this script every time the commit message has something like "Go to Production", "New Release" or anything like that can be agreed with the developer.

**Option 2**

As I do.

Every time a new tag is created I run a script that start jenkins job and create a new release.

You can also do that by creating a specific branch with name release, every time a commit is done this branch, jenkins jobs is triggered.

Comment: What I want to do is have Jenkins look at either the tag or the branches, and choose the most recent version if it's tags and if its branches, look at all the branches that start with "release" which are followed by the version number and choose the most recent one for that. What you're suggesting sounds like I'd have to manually change the string parameter each time a new release branch is created. Option 2 also seems interesting, but I don't think it fits our case as I'm trying to set up an automated job that will build everyday, rather than just everytime a commit is made.